# (PCRE Regex) How to match up to string (a) unless string (b) precedes it?

Tags: html, regex, pcre

Working with HTML, I want to match all tags containing a string. For example, I want to match all hyperlinks (separate matches; one match per complete ... tag) within each of which appears the string "click here".

Example source - I want to match each of these as separate matches:

```
<a href="/somepage">click here</a>
<a href="/somepage">please <b>click here</b> now</a>
<a href="/somepage"><img src="/someimage" alt="click here"/></a>
```

So I need to start with the opening tag (eg. `<a\s+[^>]+>`) then match "click here" but *on condition* it appears before the next closest `</a>` closing tag. For example, the following are not suitable:

`<a\s+[^>]+>.*?click here.*?</a>` matches *any* link (then all HTML) up to the first "click here".
`<a\s+[^>]+>[^<]*click here.*?</a>` only matches if no other tags exist inside the `<a>`.

Only idea so far:

`<a\s+[^>]+>(?:.*?(?=</a>))` will match everything within a specific `<a>` tag, but I don't know how to then "back-check" for text within the `(?:)` group. Is that possible?

Comment: [The pony he comes...](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454)

Comment: Which language are you using? PHP?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I understand you want to match tag  containing text "click here" and maybe another tags inside. Also you need to avoid situation when this is matched:

```
<a href="#">Hi there</a> <a href="#">Hi, <b>click here</b></a>
```

but rather match only second

```
<a href="#">Hi, <b>click here</b></a>
```

what you need is make sure, there is no ending of a tag between it's starting and "click here" text.
This should work:

```
<a\s+[^>]+>((?!</a).)*click here.*</a>
```

Comment: To prevent your regex from consuming all of `<a href="#">Hi, <b>click here</b></a> <a href="#">Hi there</a>` make the last asterisk non-greedy `<a\s+[^>]+>((?!</a).)*click here.*?</a>`. [RegEx101 demo](https://regex101.com/r/mO3aL0/1) (with escaped forward slashes).

Comment: Thanks, that indeed does the trick! However, what is the difference between `((?!</a).)*` and a "simpler" (to me) `.*?(?!=</a)`?

Comment: I am not really sure, but if it works, you can do it your 'simper' way.

Answer (score 0):

```
<a [^>]*>(?:(?!<\/a>).)*?\bclick here\b(?:(?!<\/a>).)*<\/a>
```

Try this.See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/sH8aR8/39